# Kendo Grid - How to make grid displayed grouped data by one column by default (init)?

Tags: javascript, datagrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i would like to display grouped data in grid by default?

Should I do it during the read method?

Many Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**

Model filed for the object what i want to use for default grouping is following:

```
partner: {
                                defaultValue: {},
                                nullable: false,
                                type: "object"
                            },
```

Column field is:

```
{
                    field :"partner.name",
                    title : $translate.instant('PARTNER'),
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

If i tried following in requestEnd:

```
var grid = $("#locations_grid").data('kendoGrid');
                        grid._group = true;
                        grid.dataSource._group.push({
                            aggregates: [],
                            dir: "asc",
                            field: "partner.name"
                        });
                        grid.refresh();
```

I always get empty grid.

Request strtucture for grouping is following:

```
{
    "entityName": "Location",
    "data": {
        "take": 10,
        "skip": 0,
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "group": [
            {
                "field": "partner.name",
                "dir": "asc",
                "aggregates": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT2 - WHOLE CODE OF THE GRID INIT:

```
$scope.initGrid = function() {
    // set container for loading spinner
    gridView = $("#locations_grid");
    // set all properties for data grid
    gridView.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                // READ REQUEST
                read: function (options) {
                    console.log("List");
                    console.log(options.data);
                    requestParams = {
                        "entityName": "Location"
                    };
                    requestParams.data = options.data;

                    console.log(requestParams);
                    ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                            "POST",
                            $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "location/search",
                            requestParams
                    )
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        // successful data retrieval
                        console.log("request success, checking state");
                        console.log(data);
                        // sent status to global HTTP status service
                        var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                        console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                        // do something with data
                        switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                            case true:
                                options.success(data);
                                break;
                            case false:
                                growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                break;
                        }
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                        console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                        growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                        // hide loading spinner
                        kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                    });
                },
                // UPDATE REQUEST
                update: function (options) {
                    console.log("Update");
                    console.log(options.data);
                    // ADD DATA FOR UPDATE TO THE TOKEN
                    console.log(requestParams);
                    console.log(options.data);
                    requestParams = options.data;
                    ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                        "POST",
                        $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "/location/update",
                        requestParams
                    )
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // successful data retrieval
                            // successful data retrieval
                            console.log("request success, checking state");
                            console.log(data);
                            // sent status to global HTTP status service
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                            // do something with data
                            switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                case true:
                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('UPDATED'), 'success',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                    options.success(data);
                                    break;
                                case false:
                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                    break;
                            }
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + data , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                        });
                },
                // DELETE FUNCTION
                destroy: function (options) {
                    console.log("delete");
                    console.log(options.data);
                    // add data to request params
                    console.log("delete id: " +options.data.id);
                    // call the service
                    ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                        "POST",
                        $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "/location/delete",
                        requestParams)
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // successful data retrieval
                            console.log("request success, checking state");
                            console.log(data);
                            // sent status to global HTTP status service
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                            // do something with data
                            switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                case true:
                                    options.success(data);
                                    break;
                                case false:
                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                    break;
                            }
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                            growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                            // hide loading spinner
                            kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                        });
                },
                // CREATE FUNCTION
                create: function (options) {
                    console.log("Create");
                    console.log(options.data);
                    // ADD DATA FOR UPDATE TO THE TOKEN
                    requestParams = options.data;
                    ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                        "POST",
                        $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "location/create",
                        requestParams
                    )
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // successful data retrieval
                            console.log("request success, checking state");
                            console.log(data);
                            // sent status to global HTTP status service
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                            // do something with data
                            switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                case true:
                                    options.success(data);
                                    var dataSource = gridView.dataSource;
                                    gridView.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED'), 'success',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                    break;
                                case false:
                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                    options.success(data);
                                    break;
                            }

                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                            growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                            // hide loading spinner
                            kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                        });
                }
            },
            requestStart: function(e) {
                console.log("Request start");
                // show loading spinner
                //kendo.ui.progress(gridView, true);

            },
            requestEnd: function(e) {
                console.log("Request end");
                /*
                if(e.type === "read"){
                    var grid = $("#locations_grid").data('kendoGrid');
                    grid._group = true;
                    grid.dataSource._group.push({
                        aggregates: [],
                        dir: "asc",
                        field: "code"
                    });
                    grid.refresh();
                }
                */
                var response = e.response;
                var type = e.type;
                console.log(type);
                kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
            },
            requestError: function(e) {
                console.log("Request error");
                // hide loading spinner
                kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
            },
            // SCHEMA FOR DATAGRID
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        id: {
                            editable: false,
                            nullable: true,
                            defaultValue: null,
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        partner: {
                            defaultValue: {},
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "object"
                        },
                        accessNote: {
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: true,
                            type: "string"
                        },
                        address: {
                            defaultValue: {},
                            nullable: false
                        },
                        bsc: {
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: true
                        },
                        code:{
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "string",
                            validation: {
                                required: true,
                                min: 1
                            }
                        },
                        indoorOutdoor:{
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "string",
                            validation: {
                                required: {
                                    message: $translate.instant('FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        siteId:{
                            editable: true,
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "string",
                            validation: {
                                required: {
                                    message: $translate.instant('FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        stationType:{
                            defaultValue: {},
                            nullable: false,
                            validation: {
                                required: {
                                    message: $translate.instant('FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.results);
                    return response.results;
                },
                total: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.resultCount);
                    return response.resultCount;
                }
            },
            // definition for page sorting
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverGrouping: true,
        },
        editable:{
            confirmation:true //remove delete confirm message
        },
        scrollable:true,
        //window resizing hack
        height: function () {
           return GlobalHelperService.getWindowSize();
        },
        filterable: GridHelperService.filtersTranlations(),
        sortable: true,
        groupable : {
            messages: {
                empty : $translate.instant('DRAG_SELECTED_COLUMN_HEADER_HERE_TO_GROUP')
            }
        },
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        //dataBound: resizeGrid, //callback when data are loaded
        columnMenu: GridHelperService.getColumnMenu(),
        pageable: GridHelperService.getBottomToolbar(),
        messages:GridHelperService.getToolbarButtonsTranlations(),
        toolbar: [
            { name: "create" },
            { name: "save" },
            { name: "cancel" }
        ],
        columns: [
            {
                field :"partner.name",
                title : $translate.instant('PARTNER'),
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"accessNote",
                title : $translate.instant('ACCESS_NOTE'),
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"address.city",
                title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_CITY'),
                width: 250,
                editor: GlobalHelperService.getAddressCityListForAutocomplete,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"address.latitude",
                title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_LAT'),
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"address.longtitude",
                title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_LON'),
                width: 250,
                template: function(dataItem) {
                    console.log("DATAITEM IS FOLLOWING:");
                    console.log(dataItem);
                    var html = "<div>"+dataItem.address.longtitude+"<a class=\"showOnMapBtn\" href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+dataItem.address.latitude+","+dataItem.address.longtitude+"&z=14&ll="+dataItem.address.latitude+","+dataItem.address.longtitude+"\" target=\"blank\">"+$translate.instant('MAP')+"</a></div>";
                    return html;
                    },
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }

            },
            {
                field :"address.street",
                title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_STREET'),
                width: 250,
                editor: GlobalHelperService.getAddressStreetListForAutocomplete,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"bsc",
                title : $translate.instant('BSC'),
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"code",
                title : $translate.instant('CODE'),
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"indoorOutdoor",
                title : $translate.instant('INDOOR_OUTDOOR'),
                editor: GlobalHelperService.locationTypeDropDownEditor,
                template: function(dataItem) {
                    switch (dataItem.indoorOutdoor)
                    {
                        case "Indoor":
                            return "Indoor";
                        case "Outdoor":
                            return "Outdoor";
                        case "IndoorOutdoor":
                            return "Indoor & Outdoor";
                        default:
                            return "Zvolte";
                    }
                },
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"siteId",
                title : $translate.instant('SITE_ID'),
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field :"stationType.name",
                title : $translate.instant('STATION_TYPE'),
                editor: GlobalHelperService.getStationTypeListForAutocomplete,
                width: 250,
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    });
};
```

Comment: Really nobody knows?

Comment: I have to make sure: Do you have remote data in your grid? I mean do you have in your grid's dataSource set `read` property (no `data` property)?

Comment: I have to during each read request make data grouped by given column of the object.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I do it during the read method?

Yes, I believe that is the best way. Here is the function to group after data read on 'CompanyName' field:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        requestEnd: function(e){
            if(e.type === "read"){
                var grid = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
                grid._group = true;
                grid.dataSource._group.push({
                    aggregates: [],
                    dir: "asc",
                    field: "CompanyName"
                });
                grid.refresh();
            }
        }
    },
    groupable: true,
    columns: [{
            field: "CompanyName"
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
});
```

Kendo dojo example: http://dojo.telerik.com/oRuwA

Remember that this functionality is not official supported and uses grid private field, so it can stop working after any future updating of Kendo.

---

Angular example:

```
$scope.initGrid = function() {
    gridView = $("#locations_grid");
    gridView.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            requestEnd: function(e){
                if(e.type === "read"){
                    gridView._group = true;
                    gridView.dataSource._group.push({
                        aggregates: [],
                        dir: "asc",
                        field: "CompanyName"
                    });
                    gridView.refresh();
                }
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution is not working in my case, i think that problem is with the object attribute which represent filed where i want to group. I updated my question about additional data.

Comment: I tried on single column ( which is not object), but grid is still empty (but result from server has been received). Maybe is problem in that i'm using JSON response instead of the odata from your example?

Version of the Kendo is same as in Your example.

Comment: No, it should not be a problem. I'll check if nested field (partenr.name in your case) is not a problem. I assume your grid works correclty without this requestEnd function and displays yours data?

Comment: Yes, without if(e.type === "read"){ is grid displaying ungroupped data correctly.

Comment: It's impossible :| I've updated the example maping contact Name and Title for extra property in data to check if it's problem: http://dojo.telerik.com/oRuwA/2 . And everythig is working. Maybe upload whole grid code or try reproduce problem in kendo dojo or jsfiddle becouse I don't have more ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question of whole code if grid init method.

Comment: You could tell me that this is angular :) so you can not get grid instance using jQuery `var grid = $("#locations_grid").data('kendoGrid');` delete this line and in next ones change `grid` for `gridView` (I think, I've never use angular).

Comment: I think, that getting instance of the grid using var grid = $("#locations_grid").data('kendoGrid'); is not dependent on Angular. Could You please provide updated code snippet, because i'm not exactly understand how did you mean it.

Comment: It throws unfortunaltelly following:
TypeError: Cannot read property '_group' of undefined